# Java method called twice from C++ JNI NDK function

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have some C++ NDK code calling a Java method via JNI.  The problem I have is that my Java method is getting called twice.  It seems once I get a handle to the method using GetMethodID and then call env->NewObject w/ that method ID, my java function is called.

It is again, obviously called when I call env->CallVoidMethod(obj, mid) which is expected.  I just am not sure why it is called when I create a NewObject?

```
C++ Code: 
---------
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    jvm = vm;
    start();
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void start() {    
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    jvm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/test/Test");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "StartApp", "()V");
    jobject obj = env->NewObject(cls, mid);

    if (mid != 0){
       env->CallVoidMethod(obj, mid);
    }
}       

Java Code:
----------
 public void StartApp(){
     android.util.Log.e("Test", "Java Method Called from Native");
 }
```

Comment: does Test have a constructor?  If so, does it call StartApp?

Comment: No, Test does not have a constructor. The java class does load the lib using: static { System.loadLibrary("Test_NativeSide"); }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NewObject take the constructor as parameter, so

```
jobject obj = env->NewObject(cls, mid);
```

This will invoke the first `StartApp()`, but note that since it's not a proper constructor, this will cause you trouble.

For the constructor, according to the manual, *This ID must be obtained by calling GetMethodID() with < init > as the method name and void (V) as the return type.*

Comment: Can you explain how this envokes StartApp() on the java side ?

Comment: You lie to JVM that StartApp() is the constructor, and JVM executed it. This should cause you trouble since it's not a proper constructor.

Comment: You're passing the wrong values to NewObject, basically.  You don't want to pass the method id of StartApp (what you're doing), you want to pass the id of the constructor.

Comment: Use     constructor = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V"); to get the constructor

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  Why would I set GetMethodID to my constructor and pass it to NewObject when I am trying to call StartApp() ?  I am not trying to call my constructor explicitly.

Comment: So, I modified the jobject to take a new methodID for the constructor and then CallVoidMethod taking the jobject and constructorID.  Then I get the StartApp() methodID and callVodMethod again passing that ID.  That works.